# Compiler error, cannot find symbol for whilst setting a colour

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I am trying to make a new color and place it in a Color array to switch colours  in a for loop.

```
Color LIGHTBLUE = new Color (021, 203, 223); 
Color [] colours = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHTBLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.GRAY,    Color.DARK_GRAY};
g2.setColor(colours[i]);
```

It compiles if I use just pre-defined Color references, but adding a new colour causes the failure during compiling.

Comment: What do you think `Color.LIGHTBLUE` refers to? Why do you think so?

Comment: There is no default Color.LIGHTBLUE. You are not adding the color in correct way in the array

Comment: `LIGHTBLUE` vs. `Color.LIGHTBLUE`.

Comment: In addition to your compiler error, `021` is [probably not doing what you think](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) (read the part about octal literals).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, still very new at java programming.

So the answer is

Color [] colours = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, LIGHTBLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY};

So answer is change the Color.LIGHTBLUE to LIGHTBLUE

thanks all. Some of us new here need help. :)

And wow got marked down for asking a question...:(